# C++ Rounding to the _nths place

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning c++ on a linux machine. I've got the following code for rounding down or up accordingly but only whole numbers. How would I change this code to round to the hundredths place or any other decimal? I wouldn't ask if I didn't try looking everywhere already :( and some answers seem to have a ton of lines for what seems to be a simple function!

```
double round( double ){
return floor(value + 0.5 );
}
```

Comment: Do you want to store the rounded number, or do you simply want to round for the purpose of displaying it to a user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
double round( double value )
{
    return floor( value*100 + 0.5 )/100;
}
```

to round to two decimal places.

Comment: Note, that this will not work when mantissa has large enough value.

Comment: @Tek: I think Kirill means that if the exponent (not the mantissa) is too large, such that `value*100` is greater than `numeric_limits<double>::max()`, then the calculation will overflow and give either a result of infinity, or a floating-point exception.

Comment: Last time I checked, numeric_limits<double>::max() is about 2^300. It takes a large, large, large value to overflow a double.

Comment: If the number if sufficiently large, then you don't have to round it anymore: The rounded value is not distinguishable from the original value.

Answer (score 3):

To do it generically, use the same function you've got, but shift the input up or down some decimals:

```
double round( double value, int precision )
{
    const int adjustment = pow(10,precision);
    return floor( value*(adjustment) + 0.5 )/adjustment;
}
```

(Note that you'll have to `#include <math.h>` or `#include <cmath>` to use the pow function.  If you want to write out a (less powerful) pow for this situation, you could try somrething like:

```
int intpow(int value, int power)
{   
    int r = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<power; ++i) r *= value;
    return r;
}
```

[EDIT @ Ben Voigt's comment] only calculated the adjustment once.

Comment: It's unnecessary to calculate `10**precision` twice like that.

Comment: I would like to add that: pow(10,precision)
should be: const int adjustment = pow((double)10,precision);
I messed around with my Linux compiler and although the former worked, when I tried to cross-compile the same code to windows it gives a call overload on pow(int,int&) as "ambiguous". Turns out 10 (base) should be a floating point value and not an int.